# How to pass a parameter to a function that is passed to another function as string?

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following piece of code :

```
accountSelector.executeInParallel('processAccounts', 'postProcess');


function processAccounts() {
  return JSON.stringify(syncMasterLists());
}
```

And instead of having this, I want to be able to pass a value to the `processAccounts` accounts function.

For the purpose I changed the code so it's looking like this now :

```
accountSelector.executeInParallel('processAccounts("DE")', 'postProcess');


function processAccounts(arg) {
  return JSON.stringify(syncMasterLists());
}
```

Unfortunately, after introducing the change I started getting the following error :

> Cannot find function processAccounts("DE").

I cannot understand am I doing this wrong(and if yes then what is wrong) or it's just something that can't be done.

Comment: What is `accountSelector`, and can you make changes to it?

Comment: How is `accountSelector.executeInParallel` executing the functions?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/mccapp/mccapp_managedaccountselector  @JamesThorpe this is the class. And no:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot understand am I doing this wrong(and if yes then what is
>   wrong) or it's just something that can't be done.

`accountSelector.executeInParallel` takes the function name as parameter and execute the same, `processAccounts("DE")` is not a valid function name or the name of the function that exists.

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/mccapp/mccapp_managedaccountselector#executeInParallel_3), there is a way to pass `optionalInput` parameter

> The input, if specified by optionalInput, will be passed into the
>   function specified by functionName

```
 accountSelector.executeInParallel(functionName, optionalCallbackFunctionName, optionalInput)
```

In your case, it will be

```
accountSelector.executeInParallel('processAccounts', 'postProcess', 'DE' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the function first and replace the result in the 'executeInParallel' method as follows:

```
var res = processAccounts("DE");
accountSelector.executeInParallel(res, 'postProcess');


function processAccounts(arg) {
  return JSON.stringify(syncMasterLists());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some closure can probably solve your problem, depends on how `accountSelector.executeInParallel` is implemented

```js
const accountSelector = {
  executeInParallel(pre, post) {
    let result = eval(pre)()
    eval(post)(result)
  }
}

accountSelector.executeInParallel(processAccountsWithArg('Foo'), 'postProcess');

function processAccount(arg) {
  console.log('processAccount', arg)
  return JSON.stringify({
    key: 'value'
  });
}

function processAccountsWithArg(arg) {
  return function() {
    return processAccount(arg)
  }
}

function postProcess(result) {
  console.log('postProcess', result)
}
```